# Custom XAML Binding SOURCE Class

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I am trying to find a better way to declare the ViewModel a UWP XAML Page uses.

At this moment,

1. I declare a ViewModel class `ViewModelClass` that contains my data properties.
2. Then I declare an instance of that class as `StaticResource` of the Page. I like calling those `VIEW` for consistency across all my Page designs.
3. Finally, I declare the Page's DataContext as a Binding to the `StaticResource` `VIEW`.

This yields a page that understands what data structure is in use and allows AutoComplete when working Bindings. Nice, though lots of lines of same-old-same-old code.

*Only*, it is not really suitable to ViewModels as the declared resource is a **static** resource. It is instantiated when the page is instantiated. Most pages will receive a ViewModel parameter upon `NavigatedTo`, which cannot be used to replace the static resource, because it is, well. static.

So I end up changing the Page's `DataContext` upon navigation from the initial reference to `VIEW` to the ViewModel instance I actually want to use.

Big caveat is to declare the back-reference to the page's `DataContext` when deep in the bowels of a Master-Detail situation is **rather horrible**. Imagine a collection whose display is in part depending on a Master's property.

**How do you tie back robustly to the `DataContext` of the page from anywhere inside the page?**

I have tried giving the page a Name (`PAGE` for simplicity) and then using `ElementName=PAGE, Path=DataContext.someProperty`. Ugly, plus you lose all information of the class represented by `DataContext`.

Another approach is to create a Wrapper around the actual `ViewModel` called `StaticViewModel` that has only one property: `public ViewModel viewModel`. Now I can declare the wrapper as a `StaticResource`, and tell the page's top-level `FrameworkElement` to use `VIEW.viewModel` as its `DataContext`. Works, and reliably, but sooooo ackward and cumbersome.

I would LOVE to implement a `SOURCE` class for bindings called `PageDataContext` that would do nothing else but to loop into the page and get the `DataContext` from there.
Imagine: `{Binding someProperty, Source={PageDataContext}`

**How would I go about declaring said Source class for a UWP app???**

Comment: Have you check UWP binding depth [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

Comment: Oh wait, I think I know where you are heading... `public Page.HostViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }`? Make that the property of the page and then use `{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.` to ref the property? Will try that. The question of course is why there is no framework-level reference available in the binding syntax... not like this is never needed...

Comment: Na, that's not it. It is static for the life of the page instance, not what I am looking for... Anything that would allow me to provide my own version of a Source? What is `StaticResource` based on?

Answer (score 0):

> I would LOVE to implement a SOURCE class for bindings called PageDataContext that would do nothing else but to loop into the page and get the DataContext from there. Imagine: {Binding someProperty, Source={PageDataContext}

For your requriment, you could implement your viewmodel in the page `Resources` and give it x:key.  When you bind the property of viewmodel you could access this viewmodel with x:key `Source={StaticResource ViewModel}` for more please refer the following code.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Visibility = false;
    }
    public bool Visibility { get; set; }
}
Xaml

<Page.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>

 <TextBlock
   Width="100"
   Height="44"
   Text="{x:Bind Name}"
   Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
```

Comment: Again, that refers to a STATIC resource that cannot be changed after the page instantiates. So assigning a new `ViewModel` instance to that static resource is no solution as the `OnNavigatedTo()` event where a new `ViewModel` instance will be provided can no longer change said resource.

Comment: Why you want to send the viewmodel by navigation method? in general we just send the parameter and process it in the viewmodel.

Comment: Why would I do that? I sent the ViewModel I want the page to display. That way I can have those on standby instead of instantiating them every time I am showing an aspect in a page...

Answer (score 0):

Well, no dice so far.
Working with all those options I found that the best one is a Wrapper class that can be assigned to a static resource which in turn is the basis for the page's `DataContext`. The wrapped instance of the actual `ViewModel` is then assigned during `OnNavigatedTo()` and used as the `DataContext` of the basic `FrameworkElement` of the page.

Brr, so much verbose code.

**STILL WONDERING how to implement a different version of a `source` directive. Is there no way to declare one's own `Source` for a Data Binding? Is this stuff really hard-coded into the framework???**